# How to access and modify files from my Windows installation?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I recently setup my system to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows (keeping Windows **only** to game...an addiction I just can't break.) Anyway, I noticed the */opt* and */usr* directories were taking up a lot of space on my 32GB SSD, so I decided to move them to my HDD. Here's where the idiot in me took over, I guess.

I made the fstab entry first, then rebooted the computer into a gparted installation. Well, it turns out I can't actually move the files between the hard drives from gparted (or I simply do not know how.)

So now I'm stuck in a reboot loop, and the root password is disabled disallowing me from dropping to a root prompt and alleviating the issue myself.

What can I do?

I'm stuck on Windows right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean when you say drop into a root prompt.  Most likely you're saying drop into a console prompt (where you see a black screen).

Unless you installed something special that you're trying to run after your OS installation you don't have to be concerned with the files in the /opt folder.  However, you will have to be concerned with the files in the /usr directory.  The lack of that directory will prevent normal functionality.

If all you did was move the /usr directory and it's othewise still in tact you can boon into the live disk (try ubuntu), mount that drive, and move the directory structure back to where it originally was.

When you boot into the live cd try option you'll have full access (the "root prompt") included.

You can't do this from Windows.  But you can do it from Ubuntu.

Comment: Good info. Before you answered, though, I got desperate and used the Ubuntu live CD and moved the files from the SDD /usr directory to the HDD /usr partition. Unfortunately, while it was moving, the computer fell asleep and something was corrupted. I'm now doing a fresh install. Good thing I wasn't too far into it just yet.